# Date Issue: 30/11/-0001

Tags: php, javascript

I have a java script calendar control on my webpage for managing dates, in some time the date value is stored in my DB as "30/11/-0001".

It will be more appreciated if any one help me, please.....

Comment: We need snippets of your code to even begin helping you.

Comment: The international date format is YYYY/MM/DD. Post some snippets of your code.

Comment: Hi, Its almost throght, the date is works fine when i tried in firefox, But, IE...

Comment: Its fixed, The problem is, i have used $_REQUEST and it is not posting any values to my business logic file. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some testing on your front end and get the SQL statements that are constructed with different inputs and look at what's being inserted into the database. A malformed date in the SQL query may be the culprit for the db value you're seeing.

Answer (score 6):

The date you are trying to set is probably empty. I have the same issue with a Symfony2 project where DateTime's stored in SQL with a value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' result in "30-11--0001" when parsed by Twig's date filter.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days i got the solution using **[notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)** on [php.net](http://php.net):

> **Note:** If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format,
>   the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to
>   1970-1999. See the notes below for possible differences on 32bit
>   systems (possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07).
>
> ---
>
> **Note:**
>   The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec
>   1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the
>   dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit
>   signed integer.) Prior to PHP 5.1.0, not all platforms support
>   negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no
>   earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan
>   1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few
>   other operating systems. For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range
>   of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent
>   approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

because of this problem they are showing **01-01-1970** or **30-11--0001**

So you may have to put Validation from where you taking inputs.

**From My Side: I am taking Android side value so i have created Regular Expression for that.**

**You can test [Regex](http://regexr.com/3bero) here.**

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($this->dob && $this->dob != '0000-00-00')) 
{
        $dob = date_format(date_create($this->dob), "d-m-Y");
} else {
        $dob = '';
}
```

Add this condition to resolve this date issue `$this->dob != '0000-00-00'`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is probably a combination of two things:

1. SQL server MariaDB and MySQL store unknown Dates as `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`.
2. `\DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "0000-00-00 00:00:00")` creates a date value you mention in your question.

[See here](https://3v4l.org/9Jan2)

So in the SQL world there are three types of values for DateTime and Date.

1. a valid date
2. `NULL` (provided null is allowed in the table design)
3. `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

In PHP you have null or a valid date. So the communication with the database has to decide what to do with case 2 and 3. You might want to change `0000-00-00...` to null in PHP, but this will result in a NULL value when written back, which might not be allowed in the database design.

So long story short: make sure the queries in PHP match you decision. Create a function pair for the PHP <-> SQL paradigm switch for dates. As far as I know only dates are this complex.

(Btw. JavaScript has nothing to do with this)